# How the define a selector for menu / sub-menu items

Tags: playwright

I have a navigation bar structured as following:

```
<ul class="k-widget k-reset k-header k-menu k-menu-horizontal" id="Menu" data-role="menu" tabindex="0" role="menubar">
    <li class="k-item k-state-highlight k-state-default k-first" role="menuitem"><a class="k-link" href="/Home/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="k-item k-state-default" role="menuitem"><span class="k-link">Configurations<span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s"></span></span>
        <ul class="k-group" role="menu" aria-hidden="true">
            <li class="k-item k-state-default k-first" role="menuitem"><span class="k-link">Config for A<span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-e"></span></span>
                <ul class="k-group" role="menu" aria-hidden="true">
                    <li class="k-item k-state-default k-first" role="menuitem"><a class="k-link" href="url1">SubConfig A</a></li>
                    <li class="k-item k-state-default" role="menuitem"><a class="k-link" href="url">SubConfig B</a></li>
                    <li class="k-item k-state-default k-last" role="menuitem"><a class="k-link" href="url2">SubConfig C</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="k-item k-state-default" role="menuitem"><span class="k-link">Config for B<span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-e"></span></span>
                <ul class="k-group" role="menu" aria-hidden="true">
                    <li class="k-item k-state-default k-first" role="menuitem"><a class="k-link" href="url3">SubConfig A</a></li>
                    <li class="k-item k-state-default" role="menuitem"><a class="k-link" href="url4">SubConfig B</a></li>
                    <li class="k-item k-state-default k-last" role="menuitem"><a class="k-link" href="url5">SubConfig C</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="k-item k-state-default" role="menuitem"><span class="k-link">Config for C<span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-e"></span></span>
                <ul class="k-group" role="menu" aria-hidden="true">
                    <li class="k-item k-state-default k-first" role="menuitem"><span class="k-link">Config for C-1<span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-e"></span></span>
                        <ul class="k-group" role="menu" aria-hidden="true">
                            <li class="k-item k-state-default k-first" role="menuitem"><a class="k-link" href="url6">SubConfig A</a></li>
                            <li class="k-item k-state-default" role="menuitem"><a class="k-link" href="url7">SubConfig B</a></li>
                            <li class="k-item k-state-default k-last" role="menuitem"><a class="k-link" href="url8">SubConfig C</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="k-item k-state-default" role="menuitem"><span class="k-link">Config for C-2<span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-e"></span></span>
                        <ul class="k-group" role="menu" aria-hidden="true">
                            <li class="k-item k-state-default k-first" role="menuitem"><a class="k-link" href="url9">SubConfig A</a></li>
                            <li class="k-item k-state-default" role="menuitem"><a class="k-link" href="url10">SubConfig B</a></li>
                            <li class="k-item k-state-default k-last" role="menuitem"><a class="k-link" href="url11">SubConfig C</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="k-item k-state-default k-last" role="menuitem"><a class="k-link" href="url12">Global</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

According to the documentation it is not advised to use XPath or CSS selectors. How should I write my tests:

1. to be able to test the menu structure (text displayed, order and nesting)
2. to be able to navigate by clicking on the menu item

Comment: Have you tried any code? Are you running into any issues?

Comment: I'm just starting with Playwright, so it is more like randomly poking around... 
I have tried getByRole('menuitem', { name: 'SubConfig A' }), but it returns multiple results (find all sub-menus).

Maybe adding an Id for each menu item is the solution to finding menu items, but how will I check for correct structure?

Comment: @Nafas That may not be too far off, may just need to chain that within the desired containing menu item. Something like `.getByRole('menuitem', { name: 'Config for B' }).getByRole('menuitem', { name: 'SubConfig A' })`. Though for Config for C, because of the C-2 one, you may have to tell it to use a Regex for the name or the `exact` matching option. If that ends up helping you/solving it, I can post an actual answer, just not 100% sure at the moment.

Comment: @DavidR Chaining getByRole calls look promising. I could create locators for each "path" through the menu. I'll post an update once I've tested it.

Comment: @Nafas Sounds good! If it does work, and you don’t want to have to create one per path, depending on your use case you could also create a function/method that takes the config and subconfig names (like A, B, or C-2) and returns the appropriate locator.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DavidR for the solution.

The problem why I could not find the 'Config for A' menu item was the `aria-hidden="true"` attribute on the `<ul class="k-group" role="menu" aria-hidden="true">` parent element.

the test looks as follows

```
var configurationsMenu = await page.getByRole('menuitem', { name: 'Configurations', exact: true })
await expect(await configurationsMenu.count(), 'Must have "Configurations" menu').toBe(1)

await configurationsMenu.hover()
var configForAMenu = configurationsMenu.getByRole('menuitem', { name: 'Config for A'})
await configForAMenu.waitFor()
await expect(await configForAMenu.count(), 'Must have "Configurations -> Config for A" menu').toBe(1)
```

Because of a transition on the menu, opening it requires waiting for the sub-menu item to appear `await configForAMenu.waitFor()`.

useful read https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#filtering-locators